# How to change the resolution of image in gstbuffer?

Tags: image, resize, udp, gstreamer, resolution

I am receiving data over UDP,

In Pullbuffer callback function of appsink, am retrieving the data into gstbuffer.

but that data is of 1920X1080 image buffers.

But, i would like to convert then into 720X576 resolution and stream that data.

How can i do this using gstreamer?

Comment: why dont simply use videoscale before appsink with caps you want?

Comment: can you give me some example with videoscale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using videoscale component, and videocaps i resized the image successfully.

sample pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=720,height=576 ! xvimagesink
```